# Use conda and git from same terminal (W10)

Tags: windows-10, bash, terminal, python, git

Windows 10 beginner here - currently using:

- **Anaconda Prompt terminal** to use `conda` and manage python environments.
- **git bash terminal** to use `git` and manage code.

I want to use both `conda` and `git` in the same terminal - preferably in **git bash** or some other unix-style terminal (with `cd, ls, grep`).

---

Upon researching the issue, I came across [this tutorial](https://www.earthdatascience.org/workshops/setup-earth-analytics-python/setup-git-bash-conda/) which references a step in the installation progress which I must have skipped:

> 6. Select the first option for “Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable” and [...] click on “Install”.

I did not do this during installation and I think that is the issue. What's the easiest way to do this?

---

**Note**: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is not an option.

Comment: Just to note, you don't need to enable developer mode for WSL any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so they are a few workarounds I have implemented myself, note WSL is the winner for me. I will leave you with [this link](https://github.com/sirredbeard/Awesome-WSL), maybe it will help

1. Download git and anaconda as a Windows installation and use everything under Powershell, when configuring Git Bash it shows an option where you can replace some current Windows commands for Linux. Not the best option but is a start.
2. Run a Virtual Box with your favorite Linux flavor on CLI and detachable mode and connect with ssh through a simple ssh command. Since you are using a VM you can create a shared folder between host and guest.

Answering your specific question locate where you conda installation takes place. For example C:\Users\ **your-username** \Anaconda3\ copy this path and go to file explorer right-click on "This PC" -> Properties -> Advance system settings -> Environment Variables ... -> Under System variables search for Path, left-click -> Paste conda installation directory.

Note you should close every terminal and restart it again in order for it to take effect. Sometimes a reboot is necessary. Being said the following this will most likely not work in a Git Bash window since is just a wrapper for Git. But sure will work on any CMD or Powershell instance.

Just to take into consideration from the [oficial documentation.](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/)

> **Should I add Anaconda to the Windows PATH?**
>
> When installing Anaconda, we recommend that you do not add Anaconda to
>   the Windows PATH because this can interfere with other software.
>   Instead, open Anaconda with the Start Menu and select Anaconda Prompt,
>   or use Anaconda Navigator (Start Menu - Anaconda Navigator).